# z-index not working on relatively positioned elements

Tags: html, css

Given 2 elements positioned relatively inside a relatively positioned parent, how do I get the elements to respect their z-index?

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" class="preview">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="" class="full">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    outline:1px solid blue;
}
.preview {
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    outline:1px solid yellow;
}
.full {
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
    outline:1px solid green;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Nz2g/1/

I'm trying to get the `.full` element to be placed overtop the `.preview` element, so that basically `.full` elements position isn't affected by the `.preview` element at all.

I've tried floating the elements to no avail.  **Positioning absolutely is not an option as it totally throws off the position**.  Setting `top:0;left:0` also has no effect.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: fiddling around with `z-index` in the fiddle seems to work as expected

Comment: @ralph.m I've updated the post with a short explanation.

Comment: @Markasoftware "As expected" for me would be for the .full to be overtop the .preview - were you able to get that to happen?

Comment: @Pickle here: http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/2Nz2g/2/ seems to be fine. Using chrome, version 35 or 36

Comment: screenshot: http://gyazo.com/80a833e6300cf81504065b5fa051f113

Comment: Yes, setting the images to `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` works fine. Generally best not to set z-index on the parent, unless you really need to.

Comment: @Markasoftware That requires me to know the width of the .preview element, which I won't always know.  I could get it with JS of course, but I was hoping for a CSS only solution.

Comment: @ralph.m The elements are already positioned in the center of the screen (due to some other CSS).  Setting `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` will completely mess up that positioning.

Comment: This is the effect I'm looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/yqHP8/ I've implemented it by using `background-image`

Comment: As long as the container is set to position: relative, absolute positioning won't create problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some cases where if an element is rendered after another, some browsers may ignore the `z-index` and draw them as they would do normally. In this cases you should set the `z-index` to a negative (<0) value to force them to be under the next elements:

Take a look at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QY5gq/), where all z-indexes are positive:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#first {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 10;
}

#second {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    left: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here the second `div` is rendered on top of the first one no matter what `z-index` I specify.

But take a look at [**this one**](http://jsfiddle.net/QY5gq/1/):

**HTML**:

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#first {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 10;
}

#second {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    left: 40px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

As you can see I only set the second element's `z-index` to `-1` and now it's rendered properly.

This was tested on Google Chrome 35. You may want to check this *bug* on other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Is possible for you set a top / left /rigth positions to move the div

Css:

```
.content {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    outline:1px solid blue;
}
.preview {
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    outline:1px solid yellow;
}
.full {
    top:20px;
    right:20px;
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
    outline:1px solid green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Nz2g/4/

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by using `position: relative` on the parent div and `position: absolute` on the images.  This forces the images to be aligned on top of each other

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yL5Sf/

Comment: I said absolute positioning isn't acceptable, as the position (x & y) of the images would be messed up)